# Concat for wrapped items haskell

Tags: haskell, either

I have a list of items of the type Either:
`[Right [(a, b)], Right [(a1, b1)], Right [(a2, b2)]]` and I want to get `Right [(a,b), (a1, b1), (a2, b2)]`, is it possible?
I am using sequence to do this but I get:
`Right [[(a,b)], [(a1, b1)], [(a2, b2)]]`. I was wondering, is there a function like concat which will get rid of these inner brackets, to make it just a list of tuples.

Comment: `concat <$> sequence yourlist`.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a function that for a `Left` returns a `Left` with the same value, and for a `Right` returns a `Right` where you apply the `concat` function to the value wrapped in the right so:

```
concatEither :: Either a [[b]] -> Either a [b]
concatEither (Left l) = Left l
concatEither (Right rs) = Right (concat rs)
```

then we can thus work with:

```
concatEither (sequence yourlist)
```

but this already exists: `Either a` is an instance of the [**`Functor`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) which implements this for an arbitrary function.

We can thus make use of [**`fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) or its infix operator equivalent [**`(<$>) :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-), so we can work with:

```
concat <$> sequence yourlist
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Ap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap) newtype gives you a `Monoid` instance for any `Applicative` provided the `Applicative` is itself parameterized by a `Monoid`,
which is the case with `Either x [(a,b)]`. So we could write

```
getAp . foldMap Ap :: (Monoid a, Applicative f) => [f a] -> f a
```